# How do I log from Azure to an external program?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sumologic

I need a system which reads new log entries from an azure function and outputs them to a logging program like SUMO Logic. This system needs to run outside of the azure function so as to increase efficiency within the function. I basically need a way to feed the logs into another azure function.

Answer (score 0):

The logs are stored in table storage - you could have a function run on a timer and pull the last set of logs.

Also, perhaps the functions app insights integration provides what you need?
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/App-Insights-(Preview)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using Application Insights, which works really well with azure functions now. https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/App-Insights-(Preview)